# How to send icalendar item as message content through ews?

Tags: exchangewebservices, icalendar

I want to save icalendar item as message content through ews, and here is my soap envolope looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Header>
  <RequestServerVersion xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
</Header>
<Body>
  <CreateItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">
    <SavedItemFolderId>
      <DistinguishedFolderId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Id="outbox"/>
    </SavedItemFolderId>
    <Items>
      <Message xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <MimeContent CharacterSet="UTF-8">EXCHANGE_MIME_CONTENT</MimeContent>
        <ItemClass>Message</ItemClass>
      </Message>
    </Items>
  </CreateItem>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

and here is my iCalendar item looks like

```
MIME-version: 1.0
From: testEmailAddress
Message-ID: testId
To: testRecipientEmail
Date: Fri, 15 Apr 2016 03:52:01 GMT
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?5LqL5Lu26YKA6K+377yaIOaWsOW7uuS8muiurg==?=
Content-type: multipart/alternative 
boundary="Boundary_(ID_qyG4ZdjoAsiZ+Jo19dCbWQ)"
--Boundary_(ID_qyG4ZdjoAsiZ+Jo19dCbWQ)
Content-type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8
Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Mozilla.org/NONSGML Mozilla Calendar V1.1//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Shanghai
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0800
TZOFFSETTO:+0800
TZNAME:CST
DTSTART:19700101T000000
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20160415T035017Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20160415T035201Z
DTSTAMP:20160415T035201Z
UID:9b4556c3-c85e-42b6-af0d-73c0486474ab
SUMMARY:New Meeting
ORGANIZER;testOrganizer
ATTENDEE;testAttendee
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Shanghai:20160415T120000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Shanghai:20160415T130000
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

--Boundary_(ID_qyG4ZdjoAsiZ+Jo19dCbWQ)--
```

and then I encode iCalender item with base64 EXCHANGE_MIME_CONTENT in the envelope I created before. But after saving that mail, I only receive an empty email in outbox, no iCalendar content displayed in it.
Anyone please tell me how to add this iCalendar item into an email through ews?
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

PS, my exchange server is 2007 SP1.